# vee-validator doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js

Why doesn't this code work in Internet Explorer? It works perfectly in other browsers. But this Microsoft thing is making me crazy.

```
this.$validator.validateAll().then(() => {
  var self = this;
  var toSave = self.message;
  $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: messageUrl+'/'+self.message.id,
    data: JSON.stringify(toSave),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      router.push({name : 'message-list'});
    },
    error: function (errMsg) {
      self.errorMessage = errMsg.status;
    }
  });
}).catch(() => {
  self.errorMessage= 'Correct them errors!';
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No version of Internet Explorer supports [arrow functions](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions). I know, it sucks.

Have to do it old school.

```
var self = this;
this.$validator.validateAll().then(function(){

    var toSave = self.message;
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: messageUrl+'/'+self.message.id,
        data: JSON.stringify(toSave),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            router.push({name : 'message-list'});
        },
        error: function (errMsg) {
            self.errorMessage = errMsg.status;
        }
    });
}).catch(function(){
    self.errorMessage= 'Correct them errors!';
});
```